# Returning a stringified JSON to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a JQuery script manipulate an image. So far, all the functions are working as intended, except for returning the data to PHP. I've tried several examples that I've found on Stackoverflow, yet I've been unable to return the data without any errors.

Note: JavaScript is not my primary language, my previous attempts at using Ajax have failed.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/foo/bar.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { 
            submit: JSON.stringify(format(), null, 2) 
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log("Order Submitted");
        }
    });
```

This is the error that is generated:

> designer.js:276 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
>       at format (designer.js:276)
>       at designer.js:340

`Slice` is a function inside `Format`. At the end of the `Format` function, it returns a variable `out`. I've attempted to replace the data with `data: { test: out }`, but this proved to be unsuccessful as well.

In PHP, I call the result as follows;
`$stringData = $_POST['submit'];` 
Which returns the following: `Array ( [submit] => Submit )`

When console.log(out) is called without the ajax code in place, it returns the values correctly. As soon as the ajax code is added, parts of the script stop operating as intended.

```
function format() {
var all = rects.slice().sort(function(d, f){ return d[0] - f[0]});
var lst = null;
var out = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        var cur = all[i];
        var pen = cur[0];

        if (lst != pen) {
                var locs = [];

                out.push(locs);
                lst = pen;
            }
            var ecl = cur[1].pos;
            var pos =
            {
                pos: [
                    round(ecl[0] / size.x),
                    round(ecl[1] / size.y),
                    round(ecl[2] / size.x),
                    round(ecl[3] / size.y)
                    ]
            };

        if(typeof cur[1].colour !== 'undefined'){
                pos.colour = cur[1].colour;
            }

        if(typeof cur[1].filter !== 'undefined'){
                pos.filter = cur[1].filter;
            }
    locs.push(pos);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(out, null, 2));
return out;
```

}

Comment: What is inside of the function `format()` ? Also, what is inside of your php code?

Comment: What does `format()` return? What is the logic in that function?

Comment: Can you show us the actual string output of format() ?

Comment: I added it as an answer, as it claimed there was a formatting error when I attempted to edit the original post.

Comment: @Melanchole don't add it as an answer - hit [edit] on the post and add the information there.

Comment: I'm aware, and it wasn't as intended. But it keeps giving me format errors whenever I attempt to edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the error `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` implies you're calling `.slice()` on something that doesn't exist.

The first line of your `format` function does make a `rects.slice()` - however you do not show where this `rects` variable comes from (it seems to be global).

Given this is the only call to `slice` in the code you show, what is probably happening is that the global variable `rects` is indeed undefined.

Adding `console.log(rects)` as the first line of the `format` function will help you debug it.

Comment: You're right. Rects is a global variable. It gains it's properties in a different function. Thanks for your response. It doesn't return anything other than a empty array at this stage.